# Symfony service with different value params by environment

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to set in a service different param values by environment with Symfony. The following **doesn't work**, but it's to give an idea...

config.yml

```
mytest:
   key: "VALUE_1"
```

config_dev.yml

```
mytest:
   key: "VALUE_2"
```

services.yml

```
apiclient:
    class:        My\Class            
    arguments:
        apikey: "@mytest.key"
```

Comment: `@..`is for referencing a service, you want to have a parameter, so you need to write `%myParam%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for your case it's define just a parameter:

In `config.yml` under section `parameters` add

```
parameters:
    mytest.key: "VALUE_1"
```

Similarly in `config_dev.yml` (if there's no `parameters` section, just create it)

```
parameters:
    mytest.key: "VALUE_2"
```

Then you make it:

```
apiclient:
    class:        My\Class            
    arguments:
        apikey: "%mytest.key%"
```

I don't think it's possible to make nested parameters. And [making config values](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html) is possible, but would be clear case of over-engineering in this case.

Comment: that way I don't like (and I knew it) it because normally parameters are asked after the composer install (I know its also possible skip some but I just prefer other solution)

Comment: You are not quite right. During `composer install` or `update` only those parameters are asked, which are stored in `parameters.yml.dist`. But my solution suggests to put them in `config.yml`, and in this case composer will not ask them

Comment: true, now for me your answer is valid. Thanks!